# extract certain text after certain characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

what is the easiest way with an Excel formula to extract certain details from a cell?  So for example, if this is in cell A1 **column=""HMI_LOCATE"" px=""CLASS"" position=""99"" validation=""ROOM""** then I'm trying to extract just the data the falls in between the double "" after the px= so in this example, I need to extract just the letters CLASS and nothing else, what is the easiest way to extract that data, the part I'm trying to extract won't always be 5 characters long it could be much longer or shorter.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to achieve this?

[image]

With o365 you can use this formula

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(34)&CHAR(34),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position() mod 2 = 0]")
```

or for older EXCEL-versions

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,CHAR(34)&CHAR(34),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),ROW(A1)*2),"-")
```

This splits the string at the quotation marks (`CHAR(34)`) and builds an array of elements. Then every second element is put out.

For tons of other possibilities have a look at this awesome [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml) by JvdV.

**EDIT**:
To get the element after `px=` no matter where it is, you can use

```
=LET(list,
   FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE($A$1,CHAR(34)&CHAR(34),"</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),
   INDEX(list,MATCH("px=",list,0)+1)
 )
```

The `LET`-function lets you assign functions to variables which then can be used for further calculations.

[image]

Comment: Thank you OverflowStacker for that, just tried it and yes I see the way it splits it up, never seen this view before but I am using Excel 365 now.  However, really I'm only interested in the CLASS part not the other 3 parts in this case, can they be removed so it only displays CLASS? Also, px may not always be the 2nd part of the filter that I need if px was in the third section if that makes sense?

Comment: Always nice to see an fellow FILTERXML enthusiast. You may alternatively drop LET and use xpath to return the value from wherever it is in the string.

Comment: For example: `=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(" "&A1,"""""","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[.=' px=']/following::s[1]")`.

Comment: Yeah, there is a fitting XPATH-command, but could not get it to work. If they were enumerated, i could tell you the number +wink+ (no offense). I could do it if you want.

Comment: @rnmuk Glad i could help. You can mark it as answer then. Be sure to check out the suggestion of JvdV.